# How to update some entities in datastore by uploading a csv to datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to update some entities in Datastore by uploading a CSV file.

I know that I can erase whole kind and import whole new data into Datastore which is easy. However, what I want is to update/delete specific entities which contain in the CSV file but not the whole kind. What should I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your solution and if it doesn't work, ask a question about how to fix it, instead of just asking an open "how can I?" question.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a Google Dataflow pipeline would be a good route for this. Pipeline code would look something like this

```
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import entity_pb2
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import query_pb2
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import WriteToDatastore, DeleteFromDatastore

def parse(csv_row):
    # insert logic here where you parse `csv_row`
    if action == 'update':
        entity = entity_pb2.Entity()
        datastore_helper.add_key_path(entity.key, '--KIND--', '--ID--')
        datastore_helper.add_properties(entity, {
            'field1': 'value1', 
            # full list of new values of fields to replace entity in datastore
        })
        yield pvalue.TaggedOutput('updates', entity)
    if action == 'deletion':
        key = entity_pb2.Key()
        datastore_helper.add_key_path(entity.key, '--KIND--', '--ID--')
        yield pvalue.TaggedOutput('deletions', key)

def run(project, input_file_gcs_path)
    # configure pipeline
    job_name = 'import-csv-{dt:%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S}'.format(dt=datetime.datetime.now())
    bucket_path = 'gs://{project}.appspot.com/dataflow_jobs/{job_name}'.format(
            project=project,
            job_name=job_name,
    )
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary({
        'project': project,
        'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
        'staging_location': bucket_path+'/staging',
        'temp_location': bucket_path+'/temp',
    })
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    gcloud_options = pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    gcloud_options.job_name = job_name

    # create pipeline
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    read_input = (
        p
        | 'ReadInputFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file_gcs_path)
        | 'read csv line' >> beam.FlatMap(parse).with_outputs('updates', 'deletions'))

    # `read_input` forks in updates & deletions
    _ = (read_input.updates 
         | 'write to datastore' >> WriteToDatastore(project=project))
    _ = (read_input.deletions 
         | 'write to datastore' >> DeleteFromDatastore(project=project))

    # run pipeline
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run(project="your-project-id", input_file_gcs_path="--INPUT-FILE-GCS-PATH--")
```

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.datastoreio.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.datastoreio.WriteToDatastore

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.datastoreio.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.datastoreio.DeleteFromDatastore